# What is the definition of unit vector?

Tags: vectors, dimensional-analysis, units

In many physics textbooks it is given the following definition of **unit vector**: "A unit vector is every vector whose magnitude is 1 unit". I don't like this definition.

On one hand, it is quite common to use a notation for unit vectors (for instance a hat, $\hat{u}$) different to the one used for vectors in general (usually, an arrow, $\vec{A}$). We could have a vector $\vec{A}$ in an exercise or problem and find at the end that it has a magnitude of 1 unit. ¿Would $\vec{A}$ be a unit vector? I don't think so.

I think that unit vectors arise as a consecuence of normalizing another vector $\vec{A}$, that is, by dividing it by its magnitude,

$$ \hat{u} = \frac{\vec{A}}{|\vec{A}|} $$

so that we get a vector $\hat{u}$ with just vector $\vec{A}$'s direction information.

According to units, at this point we can consider two paths:

1. Suppose that $|\vec{A}|$ has the same units as $\vec{A}$. Then $\hat{u}$ is a dimensionless quantity.
2. Suppose that $|\vec{A}|$ is dimensionless. Then $\hat{u}$ has the same units as $\vec{A}$.

I think the first option is the one that is usually used.

This last thing would also be a reason to not consider every vector with magnitude 1 unit a unit vector. In order to be a unit vector it must be dimensioness.

Is correct my definition of *unit vector*?

Comment: What do you use for the basis set of your vector space, if you can only define a unit vector with reference to some vectors in the space? To my mind, you must start with the basis vectors and use them to construct the elements of the space, not start with elements of the space and use them to construct the basis set.

Comment: You raise an important point about what dimension we assign to $|v|$. Normally, scalars are dimensionless, so that dividing by them we retain the dimension of the vector. However, it doesn't seem correct to call speed, a scalar quantity, a dimensionless scalar. And if we give it the same dimensions as the vector, then the unit vector will be dimensionless ...!

Comment: @MoziburUllah I’m struggling to understand this statement. Since when are most scalars dimensionless??

Comment: @MoziburUllah Scalars oftentimes are not dimensionless. The magnitude of a vector has the same units as do the individual components of the vector. For example, the magnitude of a displacement vector is distance, which has units of distance, and the magnitude of a velocity vector is speed, which has units of distance.time. The electric meter in the place you live registers a scalar value with units such as kilowatt-hours.

Comment: @J.Murray: I'm thinking about the definition of a vector which allows multiplication and division by a scalar. This scalar is not the same thing as you're thinking of, where a scalar is a physical quantity.

Comment: @David Hammen: For sure, see above comment.

Comment: Counter-example: Halliday, Resnick, Walker, Fundamentals of Physics Extended, 5th ed.: _"A unit vector is a vector that has a magnitude of exactly 1 and points in a particular direction. **It lacks both dimension and unit.** Its sole purpose is to point, that is, to specify a direction."_ (emphasis mine.)

Comment: @ThePhoton - Just the opposite. Vector spaces arise naturally in mathematics (in physics, they arise naturally in the mathematical model being used to describe the physical phenomena). For example, given some set $A$, the collection of functions from $A$ into $\Bbb R$ is a vector space. If there is some condition on the functions which is compatible with pointwise addition and multiplication by constants, then the set of functions satisfying the condition is also a vector space. Basis vectors are something we impose on the vector space so that we can compare it to $\Bbb R^n$ or $\Bbb C^n$.

Answer (score 43):

A unit vector has magnitude $1$ - as in, the dimensionless number $1$.  Not $1\ \mathrm{cm}$ or $1\ \mathrm{kg}$ or $1\ \mathrm{N}$ or $1\ \mathrm{J}$. It's also not hard to show that for any vector $\vec A$, the dimensions of $\vec A$ and $\vert \vec A \vert$ are the same.

Comment: Just for anyone googling here, in the humble field of computer graphics (so, you're a programmer at Pixar or an animator at Fortnite, or whatever....)  a "unit vector" has a different meaning, which may cause confusion for some readers.

Comment: @Fattie Are you sure? I'm fairly certain that, in computer graphics, a unit vector (or a normalized vector) is a vector of length 1. E.g. surface normals and tangents are often unit vectors; directions are generally represented by unit vectors. This notion is pretty universal across disciplines - linear algebra, geometry, physics, engineering... Maybe you're confusing the term with the notion of *basis vectors*? Or are you referring to the use of homogenized coordinates [x, y, z, w], where the w component is disregarded when it comes to calculating magnitude (as it's more of a "flag" value)?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović - yes, a a unit vector is of length ONE METER (or one other actual unit).     As md2perpe explains, in physics **A true unit vector has no physical dimension (like force) but only a direction.**

Comment: @Fattie - but in computer graphics, unit vectors aren't a priory associated with meters or any other unit. It's not one meter, it's just *one*. An orthonormal standard basis is assumed; this defines a sort of a global coordinate system and scale - what's sometimes called "world units". Then there's usually some global parameter that sets the scaling factor, determining how many of these "world units" fit in a meter or in a foot or whatever, but this is mostly for the artists, for consistency. After scaling, the implementation can proceed without making any reference to units. 1/2

Comment: @Fattie - In other words, what I'm saying is that in computer graphics, vectors and associated operations are based on linear algebra and projective geometry, so on the implementation side, it's all actually more in line with the mathematical (dimensionless) notion then physics is. 2/2

Comment: hi @FilipMilovanović, (sorry, I'm not sure if you work in that area, take them as general comments for any reader!), everything in (for example) Unity is a meter (and a kilogram, N⋅m, etc), and that's that.  (You can see 10^4 discussions about this online from new and hobbyist game programmers, heh.) https://answers.unity.com/questions/517442/what-are-the-real-world-measurements-in-unity.html .  NOTE THAT you can indeed in theory say it is "a foot" or "a cm" or: *one unity length measurement*.  It is one unity length measurement.  It's unrelated to the "dimensionless" in physics.

Comment: @Fattie Unity is not all computer graphics! A unit vector has exactly the same meaning on Unity than in physics (otherwise what a hell of a physics engine it would have). Perhaps then Unity enforces all length to be in meters, but the unit vectors in Unity are still dimensionless, the fact that Unity does not allow you to use other things than meters (I am just assuming this), its a Unity thing, not a unit-vector thing. The mathematics that are underlying in Unity assume that the vectors are dimensionless, or it would cause infinite bugs.

Comment: hi @AnderBiguri !  this is probably not the place for a long back-and-fore discussion.  But say in { any 3D environment at all }, perhaps an animation system...  Say there is a "joint". (Like an elbow, on Link in Zelda - you know?)  *Of course* you and I know it's not " ' really ' " a joint.  I'm sure if you are familiar with computers you know that indeed there is not " ' really ' " anything such as a vector, list, variable, array or "program", all of these things are foreign to the actual Intel chip, which deals in nand gates.  A (say) velocity vector "has" dimensions.  (Sure, yes, certainly

Comment: that abstraction is ultimately meaningless, it's all nand gates), if Link's arrow is moving at 7.6969 m/s the programmer, everyone, sees the vector as a dimensioned thing, it is *the velocity vector*.  I can assure you that if you normalize the velocity vector (so, it is now 1 m/s) everyone still thinks of it as having a dimension.  Per md2perpe's answer it *is not* "a pure direction", it is a dimensioned measure of velocity (ie "1x" some unit).  Every single part of the software and human chain is using it that way.

Comment: Pls note that you mention the "Game Physics Engine" in unity (that product is called "PhysX", there are various famous game physics engines, eg BullettPhysics, PhysX etc - Unity uses PhysX) .. a "Game Physics Engine" has utterly no connection, or very little, to "Physics" as in quantum physics etc!  Heh!  It's just a simple frame-based (step wise) calculator of torques etc on a quaternion.  And yes, everything in it is "dimensioned", length units, mass units, time units.  Again this is not the place for a long discussion so I leave it to you, cheers!

Comment: @Fattie A unit vector is any vector whose magnitude is one.  It's the same definition in physics, mathematics, engineering and computer science, *including* in computer graphics.  I say this as someone whose degree is in Math/CS and who has worked for many decades as a software developer including lots of CG.  Here's the course notes from a CMU course on Computer Graphics if you need confirmation (page 5): https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15462-s09/www/lec/04/lec04.pdf.  Software publishers often invent their own terms and redefine existing ones, but that's on them.

Comment: hi @RBarryYoung , as mentioned this is probably not the place for a long back-and-fore discussion. I already explained the viewpoint at length a couple comments up. Once again looking at md2perpe's explanation, (in physics) ***A true unit vector has no physical dimension (such as force) but only a direction.***  {BTW you posted a PDF which is a basic sort of grade-school explanation of "what is a Vector?"  Did you include the wrong link?  Or were you trying to be supercilious/humorous?  If so, heh, good one.}

Comment: @Fattie. I work with unit C++ libraries for physics,likely similar to the ones used in Unity and many other engines. The classes for the vectors in physics have assertions of the type they are. If in those libraries the unit vectors would not be dimensionless they would error, because the units after the operations would not be correct. I understand what you mean, but the underlying code is almost likely designed such that the vectors need units, and unit vectors are dimensionless. Were you to code it from scratch you can have your assumptions, but that is not how modern game libraries work.

Comment: @Fattie I see what you mean; we're talking at different levels of abstraction - I was thinking more in terms of underlying graphic capabilities—e.g. the Phong shading model, or libraries like DirectX, OpenGL, Vulcan, or vertex/fragment shaders—while you're talking more at the application level, where things may be driven by the specific needs of the application, influenced by the physics engine, or just due to the choices of developers. E.g., the needs/constraints may differ between modern game engines and 3D modeling/animation software like Blender or Max, which let you adjust the unit scale.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović , obviously you too are *100% correct* looking at it the other way.  You know, it reminds me of Richard Dawkins discussion of levels of asbtractions, as I recall in *the extended phenotype*!  Cheers  Great discussion

Answer (score 16):

I think that your confusion lies in the word "unit". In the definition of unit vector, "A unit vector is every vector whose magnitude is 1 unit," the word does not really refer to units like meter and second. It rather means just '1' and could be skipped.

A true unit vector has no physical dimension (like force) but only a direction.

If $\vec{F}$ is a physical vector (e.g. a force), then $|\vec{F}|$ is its size and has the same physical dimension (e.g. force), and $\hat{u} = \vec{F}/|\vec{F}|$ is a unit vector without physical dimension.

Comment: Fair enough. But "1 unit" in scientific context usually (or at least sometimes) means "the unit of measure in the system being used" (like 1m for length, when using SI), rather than a dimensionless 1. This means that "whose magnitude is 1 unit" is prone to being misunderstood (as the existence of this question demonstrates), while "whose magnitude is 1" is not. I would then say that "unit" in that phrase not only could be omitted but should be omitted, and its presence is simply an error.

Answer (score 9):

$(1,0,0)={(2,0,0)\over2}$.  According to your naming scheme, the left hand side is not a unit vector but the right hand side is.  This seems to be a problem.

For that matter, whenever $(x,y,z)$ has length $1$, then $(x,y,z)={(x,y,z)\over 1}$ both is and is not a unit vector.  Oops!

Comment: Yes, obviously the problem of units and dimensions disappears if you reduce everything to unit-less quantities. That's hardly an answer to a question specifically about units.

Comment: $(1,0,0)$ can always be written as $(1,0,0)/1$. But it will only be a `unit vector` if it has no physical units attached to it. Otherwise it will be only a `vector of length 1`, that is not a `unit vector` by definition.

Answer (score 4):

> In many physics textbooks it is given the following definition of **unit vector**: "A unit vector is every vector whose magnitude is 1 unit".

Yes, that is *the* definition of unit vector. I cannot remember seeing any other definitions.

> Is correct my definition of *unit vector*?

You did not actually give a definition, unless you are referring to this formula:

> $$ \hat{u} = \frac{\vec{A}}{|\vec{A}|} $$

But this formula is equivalent to the definition above, as shown below.

> On one hand, it is quite common to use a notation for unit vectors (for instance a hat, $\hat{u}$) different to the one used for vectors in general (usually, an arrow, $\vec{A}$).

Yes, if we *know* that a vector is a unit vector, we *can* use a different notation to convey this extra information. But we do not *have* to.

> We could have a vector $\vec{A}$ in an exercise or problem and find at the end that it has a magnitude of 1 unit. ¿Would $\vec{A}$ be a unit vector?

Yes, it *would* be a unit vector. We might not *say* that it is a unit vector; this does not matter.

> I think that unit vectors arise as a consecuence of normalizing another vector $\vec{A}$, that is, by dividing it by its magnitude,
>
> $$ \hat{u} = \frac{\vec{A}}{|\vec{A}|} $$
>
> so that we get a vector $\hat{u}$ with just vector $\vec{A}$'s direction information.
>
> According to units, at this point we can consider two paths:
>
> 1. Suppose that $|\vec{A}|$ has the same units as $\vec{A}$. Then $\hat{u}$ is a dimensionless quantity.
> 2. Suppose that $|\vec{A}|$ is dimensionless. Then $\hat{u}$ has the same units as $\vec{A}$.
>
> I think the first option is the one that is usually used.

It is not a choice. $|\vec{A}|$ *does* have the same dimension as $\vec{A}$, by definition. $|\vec{A}|$ can only be dimensionless if $\vec{A}$ itself is dimensionless.

You actually say this yourself: $\hat{u}$ has “just vector $\vec{A}$'s direction information”. This means that $\hat{u}$ is dimensionless.

Comment: But isn't the _"every vector whose magnitude is 1 **unit**"_ what they're asking about? If $\vec{A}$ is one meter long and points that way, then $|\vec{A}|$ is one meter, and the resulting $ \hat{u} = \frac{\vec{A}}{|\vec{A}|} $ has a length of just one. Not one meter, just a unit-less one. Which contradicts the first definition.

Comment: @ilkkachu A “unit-less one” *is* 1 unit, so there is no contradiction. This issue has already been addressed in [md2perpe’s answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/626896/279176). My answer addresses other, equally important, important issues with the question.

Comment: @BrianDrake Saying "a 'unit-less one' is one unit" rather than "a 'unit-less one' is the number 1" is utterly confusing (or just wrong if you prefer that). Why bring up the word "unit" (which could very well mean "unit of measure") again when trying to express its absence? And if you cannot remember ever seeing a definition of unit vector that does not mention "unit" in its definiens, then I think you just did not look (or remember) well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on J. Murrays answer: Every unit vector is a vector, but not every vector is a unit vector. Hence, if you use the "hat" notation to indicate unit vectors its fine to write
$
\hat u = \vec u = \vec e_u = \hat e_u = \ldots
$. So, if we consider a force of magnitude 1N pointing in the $x$-direction, we  write
$\vec F = F \cdot \hat x = 1N \;\hat x = 1N \;\vec e_x$, where $\vec e_u$ is the unit vector, not $\vec F$.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basically interpretation.

Definition of unit vector:

$$\hat{u}=\dfrac{\vec{A}}{|\vec{A}|}$$

So a `unit vector` is a mathematical object that is different from a `vector of length 1 [UNIT]`, be it meters, Newtons, whatever. This is because **by definition** the `unit vector` has **no physical units**, since its given by the ratio
of the vector by its norm (and vector and norm always have the same physical units).

Thus, you can always write any vector in terms of any unit vector without any trouble having to figure out the physical units of the quantities they represent.

For instance, say you have a force $\vec{F}=[3\hat{x}+4\hat{y}]$ Newtons. And you want a particle to displace with a velocity of 10 m/s in the same direction as $\vec{F}$. You **could represent** it in terms of the base unit vectors, $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$, by doing the scalar product, **BUT YOU DON'T NEED TO DO IT**.

Just write,

$$ \vec{v}=10 \dfrac{\vec{F}}{|\vec{F}|} [{m/s}]$$

This is possible, again, because **by definition** the unit vector has no physical unit attached to it. So it is very important to separate it from `vectors of length 1 [unit]`.

The only remark here is that if you want to derive $\vec{v}$ written in terms of the unit vector $\vec{F}/|\vec{F}|$, and $\vec{F}$ is not constant, you have to derive $\vec{F}$ as well. This is particularly important when representing your problem in a rotating frame of reference.